# For $0 < p < 1$ will my integral converge?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Will this integral converge for $0 < p < 1$?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{p}}{\log(1+x)}{e^{-x}}\mathrm{d}x$$

I tried using limit comparison test and comparison test (the only 2 tests I have learnt so far). I tried taking

$$g(x) = \frac{x^{p}}{\log(1+x)}$$

but unfortunately I can't conclude anything. Please help.

Comment: My latex isn't working. What to do?

Comment: Do you want to write this: $ \int_{0}^1 \frac{(x^p)(e^-x)}{log(1+x)}dx $ ?

Comment: Yes I edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$log (1+x) \sim x$ as $x \to 0$ and $\int_0^{1}x^{p-1}dx <\infty$. Hence the integral is finite.